# How to update specific set of Cassandra columns from Spark Dataframe using Datastax connector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Cassandra table of few columns and I want to update one of those(and also what for multiple columns?) from Spark 2.4.0. But if I don't provide all the columns then records are not getting updated.

Cassandra schema:

> ```
> rowkey,message,number,timestamp,name
> 1,hello,12345,12233454,ABC
> ```

The point is Spark `DataFrame` consists the `rowkey` with the updated timestamp that has to be updated in the Cassandra table.

I tried to Select the columns right after the options, but seems like there's no such method.

```
finalDF.select("rowkey","current_ts")
  .withColumnRenamed("current_ts","timestamp")
  .write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "table_data", "keyspace" -> "ks_data"))
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("confirm.truncate","true")
  .save()
```

Say,

```
finalDF=
rowkey,current_ts
1,12233999
```

then Cassandra table should hold the value like After the update,

```
rowkey,message,number,timestamp,name
1,hello,12345,12233999,ABC
```

I'm using Dataframe API. So rdd approach cannot be used. How I can do this? Cassandra version 3.11.3, Datastax connector 2.4.0-2.11

Comment: So changing the Savemode to "append" fixed the issue. Any clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Clarification is `SaveMode` is used to specify the expected behavior of saving a DataFrame to a data source.(not only for c* but for any datasource). Available [options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#save-modes) are

> 1. SaveMode.ErrorIfExists
> 2. SaveMode.Append
> 3. SaveMode.Overwrite
> 4. SaveMode.Ignore

In this case, Since you have already data and you want to append you have to use `SaveMode.Append`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

finalDF.select("rowkey","current_ts")
  .withColumnRenamed("current_ts","timestamp")
  .write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "table_data", "keyspace" -> "ks_data"))
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .option("confirm.truncate","true")
  .save()
```

see the spark docs here on [SaveModes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#save-modes)